# What kind of property should I be using to allow the user to specify the output data type if my device supports two different kinds

Tags: redhawksdr

I am creating a REDHAWK device that outputs either 16 bit signed complex samples, or VITA49 packets.  I want the device to be told which output type it should provide when it is allocated.

How should I go about this?

- Should I just add a simple property to the front_end_tuner_allocation struct?
- Some other recommended approach.

Is there an example that I might look at?

Comment: After some investigation I realized that I was able to setup a struct sequence property that contained a struct property that contained simple properties.  I then had to add a property listener to the constructor of the device.  Once I did this the information was modifiable prior to the device being allocated using the IDE's node explorer option.  
  
I assume that this is the way I am supposed to approach updating configurable items prior to an allocation.  
  
Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

### ANSWER

I was able to speak with an experienced REDHAWK developer.

Apparently in situations where the device is capable of producing different data flows then separate Device node specifications should be created.  This means that the output port to be used will be dictated when the device is started and should not be configured at run time.

This actually makes sense given the life-cycle of the device and the component receiving the data.

This is how I rationalize it, the component won't be able to control the device until the allocate-capacity is performed.  So there would be no way for the component/waveform to setup the device ahead of time.